# how to connect local pg db in node js app thorugh jekins build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, jenkins

```
Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...[39m[38;5;3m +67ms[39m
19:36:20 error: password authentication failed for user "jenkins"
19:36:20     at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Backend_Non-docker_deployment/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
19:36:20     at Parser.handlePacket (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Backend_Non-docker_deployment/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
19:36:20     at Parser.parse (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Backend_Non-docker_deployment/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
19:36:20     at Socket.stream.on (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Backend_Non-docker_deployment/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
19:36:20     at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
19:36:20     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)
19:36:20     at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288:12)
19:36:20     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269:11)
19:36:20     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
19:36:20     at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
```

pg_hba.conf
i have created jenkins row in this file.
host    all             jenkins         0.0.0.0/0               md5

Comment: ```password authentication failed for user "jenkins"``` Are you sure the password is correct?

Comment: yes , password is correct.